# Why is this function $2\pi n$ periodic?

Tags: calculus, periodic-functions

We have the $n$'th function defined as

\begin{equation}
f_{n}(r,\theta)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}w(r,\theta,R,\theta')cos(n\theta')d\theta'
\end{equation}

where $R$ is just some constant. I know that $w$ is $2\pi$ periodic in $\theta$ (and in $\theta'$ I think).

I can't work out how we know $f_{n}$ is  $2\pi n$ periodic in $\theta$?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $w$ is $2\pi$ periodic in $\theta$ and thus $2n\pi$ periodic in $\theta$, which implies that
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}w(r,\theta+2n\pi,R,\theta')\cos(n\theta')\ d\theta'=\int_{0}^{2\pi}w(r,\theta,R,\theta')\cos(n\theta')\  d\theta'
$$

Comment: Oh yes, ofcourse! Do you know why this then implies that the $n$'th function is symmetric with respect to rotation of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ about the origin?

Comment: Would you like to post a follow-up question?

Comment: Yes I will do that. Thanks for the answer.